# Mono make dllimport conditional?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop, dllimport

So, i've got the following code

```
    [DllImport( "kernel32.dll" )]
    static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect( IntPtr hWnd, ref Rectangle lpRect );

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    private static extern int MoveWindow( IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint );

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos( IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, SetWindowPosFlags uFlags );

    [DllImport( "User32.dll" )]
    public static extern UIntPtr SetTimer( IntPtr hWnd, UIntPtr nIDEvent, uint uElapse, TimerProc lpTimerFunc );

    [DllImport( "User32.dll" )]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage( IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam );

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx( int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId );

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    public static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx( IntPtr idHook );

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx( IntPtr idHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam );

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    public static extern int GetWindowTextLength( IntPtr hWnd );

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    public static extern int GetWindowText( IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int maxLength );

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    public static extern int EndDialog( IntPtr hDlg, IntPtr nResult );
```

I want to make the program compatible with mono, and i get that i need to use managed functions, but can i make it use the DLLImport if on windows, and my custom one if not, or do i have to stick to one of the two on all platforms ?

Comment: I don't know if it fully answers your question, but FWIW a DLLImport is only resolved once the function is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

In these cases, using conditional compilation would likely be the cleaner approach, and having a library for each platform.

```
#if WINDOWS 
    // Load Stuff 
#endif



#if LINUX
    // Load other stuff
#endif
```

Comment: I know but i haven't been able to find a definition for mono, that always exists (there is one, but the mono devs don't suggest using it)

Comment: @MonyArmenchev What do you mean a "definition for Mono"? Do you mean the compilation symbols? Those you make whatever you want, they are variables for the compiler to see so you can control conditions for gets compiled in which version you want to build. They are not in the final output, you make them whatever you want.